# Comparing image similarity using OpenCV in Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

How can I compare two images similarity in Java using OpenCV.
I must mention that those images may differ by angle, luminosity, etc.
I'm not interested in comparing identical images.
For example:
[image]

[image]

After processing these 2 images, I want to know that they contain the same object, or that they look 70% similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in Java, using ASIFT, implemented in  OpenImaj library.
Example [here](https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/master/demos/examples/src/main/java/org/openimaj/examples/image/feature/local/ASIFTMatchingExample.java)

Asift extacts local features from a image and then it's used a matcher in order to detect similar features.

ASIFT online demo here: http://demo.ipol.im/demo/my_affine_sift/